# Foundation reveal on appended content

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading some content via .append into a unsorted list element like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#player_status_5342").html('<img src=" /site/templates/images/system/loader/small_ajax_loader.gif"/>');
        $.getJSON("/api-checks/get_ingame_bool/euw/rorotan", function(result){
        console.log(result + " RoroTan");
            if(result == '1'){
                $("#player_status_5342").html('<img src=" /site/templates/images/system/status/online.png"/>');
                $("#36868417").append('<li><a href="/pages/ingame-info/euw/RoroTan" class="modal" reveal-size="large">See game details!</a></li>');
            }else{
                $("#player_status_5342").html('<img src=" /site/templates/images/system/status/offline.png"/>');
            }
        });
    });
```

player_status_5342 is a span.

And this is how I used the click event before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $(document).foundation();    
    })
    $('a.modal').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent default event
        var size = $(this).attr('reveal-size');
        var $div = $('<div id="modal">'),$this = $(this);
        $('#modal').each(function(){//Clean added classes - for repeated loads
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $div.addClass('reveal-modal '+size).appendTo('body');//Add reveal to body

        $div.empty().html('<p align="center"><img src="http://www.kadowereld.nl/images/algemeen/loader2.gif" /></p>').append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').foundation('reveal', 'open');//Create reveal with Preloader!

        $.get($this.attr('href'), function(data) {
            return $div.empty().html(data).append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').foundation('reveal');//Add ajax data to preloadr. W can use jquery $.post also.
        });
    });
});
```

I already tried to use .on("click", function(){

since that normally solved my problem but that didnt work this time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not

```
$('a.modal').on('click', function(){})
```

but

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.modal', function(){})
```

Where `document` is the closest non-dynamic parent.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. When i use this on top of my webpage it screws up all my other javascript elements/things it doesnt generate an error though... And the closest, how close? I kind of wanted this to apply to the whole <body>...

Comment: this line : `$('a.modal').click(function(event)` have to change to `.on()`. And by closest, I mean a parent (of all you `a's` who's not added after page load (by jquery)

Comment: i did change the line to the line you told me to use, but as i said it screws up all my other javascript usages

Comment: And screws up means, my javascript elements just dont work anymore

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by javascript elements don't work anymore. By the way, I inspected you code and saw some misstake. `$('#modal').each()` will loop throug 1 element since `#` return 1 element no matter how much there is in the dom. Also, `$.get($this.attr('href')...)` will not work since you have no var `$this`, maybe you meant `$(this)`.

Comment: I do have a var $this = $(this); but anyway. For example, I use foundation and the dropdown menu's doesn't work anymore

Comment: None... That is the strange thing it just stops

Answer (score 0):

[Johnvh](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4303) stated this workaround; init the widget before trying to call open.

The following works:

```
  $('<div></div>')
  .addClass('reveal-modal')
  .attr('data-reveal', '')
  .append($('<h1>Hello</h1>'))
  .appendTo($('body'))
  .foundation('reveal')     // <-- need this first!
  .foundation('reveal', 'open');
```